# Installation of Canon Laserjet LBP 2900B Printer drivers in Linux Mint-16-Cinnamon-64 bit

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, cups, printer

I have to "install" Synaptic Package Manager from the Ubuntu Software Center to the above mentioned Linux Mint version. This is the website that i visited: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/canon-drivers-for-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/.

I know that Canon LBP 2900B printer is not in the list there, but nevertheless I request you to suggest(if there is one) a roundabout solution to installing any "CUPS" compatible in Cinnamon.

Comment: http://lecramyajiv.blogspot.fr/2012/04/installing-canon-lbp2900b-in-debian.html

Comment: This guide helped me http://www.e-lokam.com/internetsoftware/cannon-lbp-2900b-printer-installation-in-mint-16/